# Scikit-learn crashing when using linear_kernel

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I'm going through the following tutorial:

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/recommender-systems-python

When I'm attempting to run the content based recommendation code, the execution halts outputting "Killed" on the terminal, which some say it's an out of memory issue. But I have 16gb of RAM on my machine, I doubt this would be an issue.

The code is crashing on the last line of this snippet:

```
#Construct the required TF-IDF matrix by fitting and transforming the data
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(metadata['overview'])

#Output the shape of tfidf_matrix
print(tfidf_matrix.shape)


#Array mapping from feature integer indices to feature name.
tfidf.get_feature_names()[5000:5010]


# Compute the cosine similarity matrix   (THE LINE BELOW CRASHES)
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

The terminal outputs this:

```
5.618207215134185
160.0
0    Led by Woody, Andy's toys live happily in his ...
1    When siblings Judy and Peter discover an encha...
2    A family wedding reignites the ancient feud be...
3    Cheated on, mistreated and stepped on, the wom...
4    Just when George Banks has recovered from his ...
Name: overview, dtype: object
(45466, 75827)
Killed
```

I've tried changing

```
metadata = pd.read_csv('movies_metadata.csv', low_memory=False)
```

to

```
metadata = pd.read_csv('movies_metadata.csv', low_memory=True)
```

But that didn't work.

What do I need to change in order to execute the code without hanging?

Comment: If your numerical datatype is 64 bit (e.g. np.float64, np.int64), your similarity matrix will need 45466 * 45466 * 8 bytes of memory, which is about 16.53 gigabytes. Have you tried subsampling the data or changing to a smaller datatype?